# Ошибка: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be C/... on line 7

Tags: php

Код:

```
1.<?php
2.    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chat');
3.    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'messages' ORDER_BY 'date'";
4.    $results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
5.
6.    if(!isset($_GET['add_message'])) {
7.       if (mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1) {
            while ($out = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                echo $out['name']." | ".$out['date']."<br>".$out['message']."<hr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы дали в качестве аргумента в функцию `mysqli_num_rows` тип `false`. Возник он потому что `$results` у вас `false`. А он возник потому, что вы не те кавычки написали в запросе вокруг имён таблицы и колонки. Должны быть обратные (там где буква "ё" на клавиатуре)

Comment: Так вот что оно... Но это почему-то не помогло(

Comment: Предупреждение никуда не делось

Comment: Значит: а) вы не сделали то, что я написал ..... б) сделали, но не так ...... в) запрос в принципе невереный и возвращает false. Ставлю на "б" %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там еще `ORDER_BY` с подчеркиванием. Какая-то видимо инновация от топикстартера.

Comment: @u_mulder эх, значит надо было ставить на "в)"  %)))

Comment: Тю, нужно было ORDER BY без подчёркивания писать... Хотя с кавычками тоже спасибо :>